# Slide from one view controller to another in OSX swift

Tags: macos, swift, nsviewcontroller

I am fairly new to the OSX development and I am finding difficulty on getting some helpful material on the oSX development.

I want to slide from one view controller to another. How do I do that?

I know how to get from one view controller to another. When a button is pressed on the controller another view controller pops up. I dont want that. I want to slide from one view controller to another. Is there a way to do that?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you mean "slide" animation from one controller to another, or "slide" like swipe gesture to bring another controller?

Comment: Slide animation would be better

Answer (score -1):

Navigation controller does exactly what you want(it is its default animation), create storyboard file, drop navigation controller in there, set it as initial view controller and there you have it.

Here is a very useful tutorial for storyboards and navigations: http://www.raywenderlich.com/81879/storyboards-tutorial-swift-part-1

Comment: I know that it exists for IOs but i want it for OSX